# How to pass a MySQL data from PHP to Javascript through a function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm making a program that shows several descriptions taken from a database (MySQL):

```
echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"Boton" . $i . "\" value=\"Mostrar Descripcion\""
                                            . " onclick=cambiarBoton(" . $i . ", \"" . $row["descripcion"] . "\") />";

echo "<div class=\"entrada-descripcion\" id=\"Descripcion" . $i . "\">  </div>";
```

where $row["descripcion"] is the access to the description and $i is an identifier because i'm using loops. That code generates a button that i must press to show the description. The javascript function "cambiarBoton" is the one that do that changes:

```
function cambiarBoton(i, d){

                    if (document.getElementById("Boton"+i).value == "Mostrar Descripcion"){
                        document.getElementById("Boton"+i).value = "Ocultar Descripcion";
                        document.getElementById("Descripcion"+i).innerHTML = d;
                    }else if(document.getElementById("Boton"+i).value == "Ocultar Descripcion"){
                        document.getElementById("Boton"+i).value = "Mostrar Descripcion";
                        document.getElementById("Descripcion"+i).innerHTML = "";
                    }

                }
```

Ok, but there is a problem in the program and this is that i can't pass the description to the function in javascript and this doesn't works. How can i do this? 
(I must do this without using AJAX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the call of the function "cambiarBoton" in the code PHP,
it should have been this:

```
echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"Boton" . $i . "\" value=\"Mostrar Descripcion\""
                                        . " onclick=\"cambiarBoton(" . $i . ", '" . $row["descripcion"] . "')\" />";
```

And then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to the question I **think** you're asking is:

```
<?php echo "<script>var data = ".$row["description"].";</script>"; ?>
```

Comment: No, I think that the problem is in the variable  . $row["descripcion"] . that is used in the first php code, maybe it is not accepted by the function in javascript but i don't know because i print it between double quotes, and i think that this should appear something like this: onclick=cambiarBoton(5,"this is a description"); (where 5 is a random number without any importance)

Comment: The answer isn't enough, because i have several descriptions that i must use in diferent times depending when i press one button or another one, so i think that the code you give me declares that variable as a global one, but i need to use in javascript a specific one depending in the situation. Think that i have several rows with several descriptions.